# Repeat an AJAX call Until JSON response shows process complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to convert a middleware (PHP type) page which bulk sends emails into a jQuery/Ajax Page, sending one email at a time. Which is invoked by a calling ajax function. I want to synchronously repeat the ajax call until the json response eg data.status = "finished", each call will return data.percentage, (percentage complete) to progressively update a simple progress bar. As well as this I would like to include a "stop" button to cancel the broadcast. The calling page won't know how many calls it needs to make. The middleware will generate the next email and talk directly to the SMTP host and mark that email as sent, work out how far through it is so it can send back the percentage done.

I have seen some variations of this, but most solutions seem to know how manu times to loop the ajax call.

Any code snippets appreciated. Here is my code without any loop or stop code.

```
jQuery("#sendButton").click(function() {
   var ezineid = jQuery("#ezineid").val() ;
   var percentage = 0 ;
   var status = "" ;
   jQuery.ajax({  url: '/cms/emailsend.lasso',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       async: false,
       data: {
       ezineid: ezineid
       },
       success: function(data) {
           // have the html to display now
           percentage = data.percentage ;
           status = data.status ;
           // update the progress bar  
           // data.status = finished?
         }
   });
});
```

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question, because without that we cannot help. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
         $.ajax({
             url: "test.html",
             context: document.body
         }).done(function() {
          clearTimeout(timeout)
});
    }, 100);
```

You can try this, but you will need node.js and sockets if you want to listen for an event to happen.

Comment: It might be possible to use node.js but that would require rewriting the email generator and sender, which would not be a trivial task. The emails we are sending are template driven responsive emails containing around 16 news stories and images.

Comment: Why would the server side need to be rewritten in Node just to use sockets? There are PHP implementations of websockets.